# Converting ansible file permission commands into Linux console terminal commands

Tags: ansible

I am setting a demo server and I have a question about ansible file permissions.

ansible tasks are as follows:

```
- file: path=/etc/testpathA group=groupA mode=660 recurse=yes state=directory
- file: path=/etc/testpathB group=groupB mode=770 recurse=yes state=directory
```

I am trying to use this command in console terminal of Linux server directly but I cannot find in google about it. I need a little help here.

Comment: if you want to execute this commands by hands, use `mkdir`, `chown` and `chmod` commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's actually more than one command here for example in

```
- file: path=/etc/testpathA group=groupA mode=660 recurse=yes state=directory
```

try these in the shell

```
chgrp -R groupA: /etc/testpathA
chmod -R 600 /etc/testpathA
```

Hope this helps